# Symfony2 Query placement

Tags: php, symfony

I have a simple question.

Should i place queries made with the entitymanager in the controllers or should i make separate classes and then call it with a service ?

example of query outside the controller :

```
protected $entityManager;
protected $securityContext;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, SecurityContext $securityContext) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
}

public function getTest() {
    $query = $this->entityManager->getRepository('PdbTestLoginBundle:PdbDomain')->find(972);
    if (!empty($query)) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then i register a service like this :

`parameters:
    test.controller: Pdb\TestLoginBundle\Classes\Test

services:
    test.defaultcontroller:
        class: "%test.controller%"
        arguments: 
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            securityContext: "@security.context"

then i call it in the controller :

`$helper = $this->get('test.defaultcontroller');
var_dump($helper->getTest());

Is this the right way or should i directly make the query ???

Comment: You should put your query builders in Repository classes and tell the Entity class to use your Repository classes -- this means that $em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity') gives you an object of your new Repository class.

Comment: So i need to generate for each entity a Repository Class?

Comment: Not necessarily "for each". You can generate a Repository only for the entities you need a repository.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your query builders in Repository classes and tell the Entity class to use your Repository classes.

Repository classes have to extend `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` class.

This means that `$em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')` returns an object of your new Repository class.

Comment: Instead of creating your Repository class manually, you can also use the annotation `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyEntityRepository")`, and then run the `doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle:MyEntity`command.